# How to use bootstrap pagination with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am a working with php and mysql and I managed to do pagination following this tutorial:
http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Here is "mywebpage" (on work): http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/miejemplo.php

But Now, I want to make it "pretty" using bootstrap Pagination:http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

I am using _GET['current_page'] to get the page where I am. The problem is that I dont know how to change the echo's to echo the pagination from bootstrap... Yes, it may be stupid, but It is my first time with php and I am like 2 hours just trying to do this. Can someone help me? Below is the code that I have, following the tutorial of php freaks (which I understand, except for some echos with toomany quotes :/ ):

```
    <div class="pagination">
    <ul>

    <?php
    /******  build the pagination links ******/
    // if not on page 1, don't show back links
    if ($currentpage > 1) {
        // show << link to go back to page 1
        # TRYING TO CHANGE HERE AND IN OTHER ECHOS  
        #echo "<li><a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1\">&laquo;</a></li>";
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
        // get previous page num
        $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
        // show < link to go back to 1 page
        #echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'><</a> ";
    } // end if

    # range of num links to show
    $range = 3;

    # loop to show links to range of pages around current page
    for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range)  + 1); $x++) {
        // if it's a valid page number...
        if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
        // if we're on current page...
            if ($x == $currentpage) {
            // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
                echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
        // if not current page...
        }
        else {
            // make it a link
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
        } // end else
    } // end if 
} // end for


    // if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
    if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
        // get next page
        $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
        // echo forward link for next page 
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>></a> ";
        // echo forward link for lastpage
        echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
     } // end if
     # end build pagination links 
?>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not really put your `.sql` files in publicly accessible folders..e.g http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/basededatos/hpcf_tables.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, Bootstrap pagination works on a ul of class = pagination with the page links as list items.

Towards the start of your php code add the pagination class to the ul (not the div)

```
<ul class="pagination">
```

Then wherever you echo a page link, wrap it with li tags, e.g.

```
echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> </li>";
```

**EDIT**
You also want to tweak the HTML for the current page by changing

```
echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
```

to

```
echo " <li>$x</li> ";
```

**Edit**
If you want to center your pagination bar, Bootstrap 3 has a the text-center class which you can use. See http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/8RHzw/
Change the first line of your php to

```
<div class="text-center">
```

With Bootstrap 2, use

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, David. I will try it now (keep around lol). The bootstrap folder is not there: http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/bootstrap-3.1.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js Where I should put this files? So that it read the files? I am using the basic template from bootstrap (Basic template section): http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Hi again, it is working (kind-off): http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/miejemplo.php But it does not display the page where I am (I think I can try to fix it). Also, how I can make it to be in the center?? I tried something like <ul class=pagination style="aligment:center"> but it does not work... Did you know the correct command for this?

Comment: Ok, I managed to get what I want:  ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/miejemplo.php  But i want it in the center... How I can put the navbar in the center? I google stuff of this but the talk about CSS... any ideas?

Comment: @Edwardo, please see my update on how to center the pagination bar

Comment: that worked just fine! thanks! I have a last request: I am trying do a search page: http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/search.php I want a dropdown button with some words (ip,hostname etc.) so that I can know where to to search. Did you suggest doing this with html and then a php (results.php) to process the information of the search? Also, should I use get or post (dont know the exact difference yet)? thank you! @David

Comment: @Edwardo , http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp has a reasonable summary of the advantages of GET vs POST. For your other question, you might be able to make your form using a BS dropdown button (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns). Personally I would start by choosing a good search module, one that does what I want, and then work backwards from there to build myf search and result pages.

Comment: Thank you for the information! What do you mean by a search module? You mean to do an html and then quering the results? I was thinking to do just a search using like in the query..

Comment: @Edwardo There are many ways to add search capability to a website and so I can't give specific suggestions without knowing more details. Perhaps you should start working on a search page. Then if you need additional help you could post another question and include a link to what you've done? Good luck!

Comment: Hi again, I have an html search page (php no implemented yer), please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331646/bootstrap-form-how-to-use-with-post Is bootstrap related. It will be nice if you can help me! Thanks. @David Taiaroa

Answer (score 0):

Further to David Taiaroa's answer above, for the active button state you need to add the class="active" and A tags.

```
echo " <li>$x</li> ";
```

..becomes..

```
echo " <li class=\"active\"><a>$x</a></li> ";
```