# Bootstrap form, how to use with POST

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a class project and I have a webpage to do search:
http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/basicsearch.html

Here is the basic code:

```
<html>
<head> <title>Search HPCF Inventory</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Search </h1>

    <form action="results.php" method="POST">
    Choose Search Type: <br />
    <select name="searchtype">
        <option value="ip"> IP Adress </option>
        <option value="ss_name"> Software Services </option>
        <option value="IS"> ISBN </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    Enter Search Term:<br />
    <input name="searchterm" type="text">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to make it "pretty" using bootstrap 3. I want exactly what I have in my webpage but to be honest, I don't understand the forms of bootstrap (I am new with webpages), mainly how to say that it is by POST and how to put the variable names. I have been looking for this in websites like this: http://bootsnipp.com/forms?version=3

Which looks really cool, but I don't understand how to edit it...
Can someone share the necessary code to have the exact thing that I have in my webpage using bootstrap?

Thanks.

Comment: I understand how the html that I have works, and I am using php to get the data. The php part is not implemented. Asyou can see, what I want is just to use bootstrap so it looks more nicer.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: thanks, but how I put, for example, <form action="results.php" method="POST"> in the bootstrap form? and also the select variable?

Comment: BS is largely a CSS framework with some extra javascript. So say the HTML for your form is <form action="results.php" method="POST"> and the BS HTML is <form class="form-horizontal">, add the BS class to your existing code. i.e. <form action="results.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">. BS often adds extra spans, eg <div class="form-group"> For best results copy these across as well because they are usually for consistent cross-browser styling or for accessibility or just good practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read through and follow the example at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

So,  would end up being

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="searchterm" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose Search Type</label>
    <select name="searchtype" class="form-control">
      <option value="ip"> IP Adress </option>
      <option value="ss_name"> Software Services </option>
      <option value="IS"> ISBN </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="searchterm" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Choose Search Term</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchterm" name="searchterm">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. It looks like this: http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/newej.html How I can put it so that the dropdown bar and the search bar be smaller?

Comment: change the col-sm-10 to col-sm-8 / you can also wrap the whole thing in a <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2>...formcode...</div></div> too.

Comment: ok Thanks. Now it looks like this: http://ada.uprrp.edu/~ehazim/hpcf_proj/newej.html Last request: Is there a way to force that "Search type" Appears at the left side of the bar, like in the Search Term bar?

Comment: wrap the <select> in <div class="col-sm-10"> as well.

Comment: I forgot to incorporate the name attribute in the select tag. Thanks.