# How to create dropdown with rails form using bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, forms

The form tag below works. However, I wanted to add styling and substitute `text_field_tag` into dropdown select so user can select the hours.

```
<%= form_tag("/availability", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:available_hour, "Add Availability:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:available_hour) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Add") %>
<% end %>
```

I am having trouble creating form with dropdown select using bootstrap form. I tried:

```
<form method="post" action="/availability">
  <select class="custom-select">
    <% (1..24).to_a.each do |el| %>
      <option value=el><%= el%></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But it gave me `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

This is done inside user show view, and the action I am firing is from Availability model' create action.

I found a relevant [SO post on bootstrap form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331646/bootstrap-form-how-to-use-with-post), but the answer uses PHP. This is what he used: `<form action="results.php" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal">`.

I think if I can somehow point to bootstrap to look for `Availability`, it should work.

How can I point out to bootstrap form which controller (and method) to use?

Comment: shouldn't the value of the option tag be `<%= el %>` ? so the whole line of code should be like `<option value=<%= el %> ><%=el%></option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably omitting a CSRF value that's automatically included by `form_tag`.

Try adding

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Or you can add it to the form block directly:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

Comment: I deleted my old comment. I stand corrected, I tried the `hidden_field_tag` and it fixed it. I also made other modification to the code and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

form_tag helper [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), you can add option , authenticity_token: false

actually rails already has actionview helper to help you create dropdown with hour here is [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_hour)

for your problem you can try

```
<%= form_tag("/availability", method: "post", authenticity_token: false) do %>
  <div class="row form-group">
    <%= f.label "Add Availability:", :class => 'control-label col-sm-3' %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= select_hour :available_hour, :class => 'form-control') %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```