# Form in a bootstrap modal doesn't insert data in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to insert data to MySQL with a form that is in a Bootstrap modal but it doesn't work.

I don't know why but my form method is POST and it seems to be a GET because it prints the data in the web address.

When I try to insert the data through a basic form with the same php code (no format, simple as hell) it inserts the data.

---

Here's my form in the bootstrap modal.

```
<div class="container 2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newRoute">
    CREAR NUEVA RUTA
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="newRoute" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <form class="route" method="post">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Ponle un nombre a la ruta</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="city">Ciudad</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="length">Distancia</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="length" name="length" required>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="start_point">Punto de salida</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start_point" name="start_point"
                                           required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="difficulty">Dificultad</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="difficulty" name="difficulty"
                                           required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="date">Fecha de la ruta</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="description">Detalles de la ruta</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="description"
                                              name="description"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                            value="Enviar">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my PHP code

```
include('db/db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Adjudicar name a variable
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);

// Adjudicar city a variable
$city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $city);

// Adjudicar length a variable
$length = stripslashes($_POST['length']);
$length = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $length);

// Adjudicar start_point a variable
$start_point = stripslashes($_POST['start_point']);
$start_point = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $start_point);

// Adjudicar difficulty a variable
$difficulty = stripslashes($_POST['difficulty']);
$difficulty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $difficulty);

// Adjudicar date a variable
$date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $date);

// Adjudicar description a variable
$description = stripslashes($_POST['description']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $description);

// QUERY
$query = "INSERT INTO routes (name, city, length, start_point, difficulty, user_id, date, description) VALUES ('$name','$city',$length,'$start_point','$difficulty',".$_SESSION['id'].",'$date','$description')";

// Se realiza la query
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

//Condición si se realiza la query correctamente
if($result){
    header("Location: routes.php");
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$query.'");</script>';

}else{
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR");</script>';
}}
```

my db.php (connection to database)

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', "", 'users');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

PS. When I submit the form, this is what appears in the address (all the fields were filled by sample text). It seems to be a get form.

```
http://localhost/Proyecto/routes.php?name=Test&city=Test&length=20&start_point=Test&difficulty=Test&date=2018-05-12&description=Test+description&submit=Enviar
```

Comment: define form action

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331646/bootstrap-form-how-to-use-with-post?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible but not.
I defined form action but it still acts as a GET because it write the form data in the web address

Comment: this code is look fine as you need form action and method here is good explanation, https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have forget to close any other form somewhere on your code that should be with `method="get"` or without method attribute 
and so when you submit the data it gets the method  from that form.
The code you have publish here should work correctly.

Comment: Was this. I had a form opened upper in the navbar and worked after deleting it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your form code is correct, **I have checked it on my system**. You must be checking/testing some other page or form.